# Nuxt appolo module How to send authorization header?

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, faunadb

**I try to use nux.js with apollo. I have to send an authorization header.In my nuxt.config.js Itry this :**

```
    apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: 'https://graphql.fauna.com/graphql',
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxx'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But I have this error when try to make a query:

"GraphQL error: Missing authorization header".

**How can I send the header ?**

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

i used package called ‍‍‍`js-cookie` and

const token =  Cookies.get('tokenName')

```
headers: {
           Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
}
```

and i think it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you store your token in cookie, you can use tokenName property for specifying name of your token cookie:

```
apollo: {
  clientConfigs: {
    default: {
      httpEndpoint: 'https://graphql.fauna.com/graphql',
      tokenName: 'NAME_OF_TOKEN_COOKIE'
    }
  }
}
```

It automatically attaches value from cookie to authentication header in apollo requests.

Answer (score 0):

Been seeing this error with websockets setup (with `lazy` and `reconnect` set to true), though might be relevant.

The reason was that after logout, `header.authorization` was set to null, which was wrong, the whole header should've been set to null:

```
// Return header if token set, else - null
const getHeaders = () => {
  const token = store.getters[AuthS.extGetToken]
  if (!token) return null

  return { authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
}

// Create a WebSocket link:
const link = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: config.backendUrl,

  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    lazy: true,
    timeout: 30000,
    connectionParams: () => {
      return { headers: getHeaders() }
    }
}
```